# Could not find or load main class in Groovy gradle project

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I have groovy application that i want to pack in executable jar with gradle.
The problem is when the jar is done i have error: Could not find or load main class .
Here is my build.gradle:

```
group 'com.demo'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

 apply plugin: 'groovy'
 apply plugin: 'java'
 apply plugin: 'idea'
 apply plugin:'application'
 mainClassName = 'com.demo.App'


 buildscript {
      repositories {
          mavenCentral()
      }
      dependencies {}
 }

  repositories {
   mavenCentral()
  }
  // java version dependency
   sourceCompatibility = 1.8
   targetCompatibility = 1.8

  jar {
baseName = 'cim-configurator'
version =  '0.1.0'
manifest {
    attributes("Build-Time": new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),
            "Build-Jdk": System.getProperty("java.version"),
            "Built-By": System.getProperty("user.name"),
            "Created-By": "Gradle",
            "Main-Class": "com.demo.App"
    )
  }
}
```

Here is the file hierarchy:

```
com.demo
   ActiveMq
   App
   Database
   Rbac
   Run.groovy
   Service
```

Comment: How do you get this error ? From which command ?

Comment: When i try to start the jar with java -jar

Comment: Please also add the file hierarchy.

Comment: @cfrick I edited the question

Comment: My guess here is, that you lack the dependency for `groovy` (e.g. `groovy-all`) and the error here actually hides that fact it can not see `GObject` and friends.  I am yet not really convinced what files here are groovy and what are java and what are the sources actually (from your partial tree).  So i am surporsed this even built.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that using uberjar will fix your problem. It worked with similar case for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this [exact same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55697453/gradle-groovy-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class?noredirect=1#comment98077378_55697453) in a Groovy & Gradle project.  This is [the answer that fixed this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55703292/715608).

**TL;DR**

Use the [Shadow-jar plugin](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) by adding the following plugin to your plugins block in build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '5.0.0'
}
```

Then run `./gradlew shadowJar`

You'll get a jar file `emailer-all.jar`, which can be run.