# Gradle & Groovy - Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I can run my project using `gradle run`, but I can't run the jar file using `java -jar`.  I've recreated the error with this sample project: [link to project on GitHub](https://github.com/tonyerskine/emailer)

This is the output from running the project via `gradlew`

```
$ ./gradlew run

> Task :run
Hello world.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 4s
```

This is the output from running the project `java -jar`

```
$ ./gradlew build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 6s

$ java -jar build/libs/emailer.jar 
Error: Could not find or load main class us.company.emailer.App
```

But when I `unzip` the `jar`, I can see `App.class`

```
user@computer:../libs$ unzip emailer.jar 
Archive:  emailer.jar
   creating: META-INF/
  inflating: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF    
   creating: us/
   creating: us/company/
   creating: us/company/emailer/
  inflating: us/company/emailer/App.class
```

Here's the `build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id 'groovy'
    id 'application'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.5.6'
    testImplementation 'org.spockframework:spock-core:1.2-groovy-2.5'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-email:1.5'
}

mainClassName = 'us.company.emailer.App'

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
            'Class-Path': configurations.compile.collect { it.getName() }.join(' '),
            'Main-Class': 'us.company.emailer.App'
        )
    }
}

sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ['src/main/groovy']
```

Here's the `App.groovy`

```
package us.company.emailer

class App {

    String getGreeting() {
        return 'Hello world.'
    }

    static void main(String[] args) {
        println new App().greeting
    }
}
```

**EDIT: Adding `MANIFEST.MF` in response to the comment from @tkruse**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: commons-email-1.5.jar javax.mail-1.5.6.jar activation-1.1.
jar
Main-Class: us.company.emailer.App
```

Comment: Did this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924932/gradle-could-not-find-or-load-main-class

Comment: @Kon , thank you for your comment. Yes, I looked at the accepted answer to that question, and it certainly did help. That's where I realized that I needed to set `sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ['src/main/groovy']`  Before that, I didn't even have a class file in my jar.  But I still get the error. I'm open to more ideas. Thanks!

Comment: It might help to post the contents of the MANIFEST.MF file from inside the jar.

Comment: @tkuse , you were right on the money.  That's where the problem see tim_yates answer below.  Thanks!

Comment: @kon , I was incorrect. As it turned out, `sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ['src/main/groovy']` wasn't necessary.  I checked out the docs (https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/groovy_plugin.html) for the groovy plugin.  First, it should have been `sourceSets.main.groovy.srcDirs`; and second, it was unnecessary since my project layout, `src/main/groovy`, already matched the default Groovy layout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the classpath.  If you look inside the `META-INF/MANIFEST.mf` file, you can see it's set to:

```
Class-Path: commons-email-1.5.jar javax.mail-1.5.6.jar activation-1.1.
 jar
```

When java runs, it has no idea where any of these things are, it also requires the groovy runtime in order to understand your groovy code.

The simplest way of doing this is to bundle all your dependencies into a "*fat-jar*", and the simplest way of doing this with Gradle is the excellent [Shadow-jar plugin](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow).

If you add the following to your `plugins` block in `build.gradle`:

```
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '5.0.0'
```

(You can delete the `jar` block and the line that manipulates the sourceSets)

Then run `./gradlew shadowJar`

You'll get a jar file `emailer-all.jar`

Which can be run:

```
$ java -jar build/libs/emailer-all.jar
Hello world.
```

For completeness, here's the complete build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'groovy'
    id 'application'
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '5.0.0'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.5.6'
    testImplementation 'org.spockframework:spock-core:1.2-groovy-2.5'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-email:1.5'
}

mainClassName = 'us.company.emailer.App'
```